# É possível editar um arquivo JSON localmente?

Tags: javascript, json

Estou começandi a aprender a usar JSON e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer operações com ele(leitura e escrita) de forma local.

Basicamente um arquivo .json com alguns dados e um.arquivo HTML.

É possível acessar esses dados e incluir novos de forma totalmente local? Sem precisar hospedar em algum servidor?

Comment: por razões de segurança o navegador não altera dados locais, mas você pode salvar o `json` no localStorage e fazer alterações nele

Comment: Além da opção `localStorage`, você também pode utilizar o IndexedDB. Esta é uma boa solução para arquivos "grandes". Além disso você poderá fazer um sistema de exportar/importar um arquivo.

Comment: Ricardo, Mas usando esse localStorage as alterações ficaram salvas apenas nele e não no arquivo Json na minha máquina, certo? Por exemplo, se eu incluir um novo valor o meu arquivo local não sofrerá alterações.

Comment: é possível com node. Há o módulo npm `jsonfile`.

Comment: Sim, é possível. Você pode usar o lowdb para isso. Segue o link para baixar e ver uns exemplos: https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/tree/master/examples